# Time to access list position v. check pertenence to set

Tags: python, list, set

I needed to make an index of ASCII letters so was checking if making an adhoc index with a list was faster than doing it checking pertenence to set. Surprisingly the list accessing is slower than checking set pertenence when measuring times for the codes beneath. Even replacing the ord() by a literal the code is still slower. Whats the explaination for this behaviour?

```
lista = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
lset = set(['a','i','j','k','l'])
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    if lista[ord('k')-97] == 1:
        pass
t2 = time.time() - t1
print(t2)

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    if 'k' in lset:
       pass  
t2 = time.time() - t1
print(t2)
```